# Web Api oData v4 $ref 404 or server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

### Problem

I am able to successfully GET the related items from either end of this relationship using the following:

- http://localhost/api/Exercises(1)?$expand=Measurements
- http://localhost:49540/api/Exercises(1)/Measurements

Now I am trying to manage the relationship between them. There are a few examples Ive found out there that Ive tried and none work. [Heres one](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataServiceSample/ODataService/Controllers/ProductFamiliesController.cs) and [heres another](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/2c4c8738d097e993822ec9ca5088d224979ab430/WebApi/v4/ODataQueryableSample/Controllers/CustomersController.cs).

### Models

```
public class Exercise
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; }
}

public class Measurement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
}
```

### Actions

Here are the actions I have tried and their requests:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteRef([FromODataUri] int key, [FromODataUri] string relatedKey, string navigationProperty)
{
   return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

URL: http://localhost/api/Exercises(1)/Measurements$id=http://localhost/api/Measurements(4)

Result: 404

```
[HttpDelete]
[ODataRoute("Exercises({key})/Measurements({relatedKey})/$ref")]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteMeasurementFromExercise(int key, int relatedKey)
{
   return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

URL: n/a

Result: Server error: `The path template 'Exercises({key})/Measurements({relatedKey})/$ref' on the action 'DeleteMeasurementFromExercise' in controller 'Exercises' is not a valid OData path template. The URI segment '$ref' is invalid after the segment 'Measurements({relatedKey})'.`

### Related

[This guy](http://forums.asp.net/t/2010431.aspx?Delete%20OData%20Reference) had the same symptoms and was able to resolve it after Microsoft released a fix. I am running with the latest versions of Web API and oData and still have this problem.

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="5.9.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net46" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, minutes after posting a question to SO, the answer to the problem Im stuck on for days comes to me.

According to the **Deleting a Relationship Between Entities** at the bottom of [this documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4), my URL should look like this:

`DELETE http://host/Suppliers(1)/Products/$ref?$id=http://host/Products(1)`

for an action like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult DeleteRef([FromODataUri] int key, [FromODataUri] string relatedKey, string navigationProperty)
{
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

**The documentation is wrong**. After some digging, I found your url should look like this:

`DELETE http://host/Suppliers(1)/Products(2)/$ref`

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to get past this issue earlier, I found painfully, is to review the entity metadata file retrieved from your global discovery URL. It will include in it both entities on either end of the relationship, and any join tables for many-to-many relationships. This will give you the valid names to use for each object.

MS needs to seriously fix and improve the user experience with the CDS or just drop the Fing thing already. It has been an obtuse nightmare for well over a decade.