# CreateRef method migrated to .Net Core results in 404, how to implement Create Relationships in OData with .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I have 2 POCOs, Lessons and Traits with int PKs.
I have navigation properties set up such that I can successfully `$expand` like so:

- `http://localhost:54321/odata/Lessons?$expand=Traits`
- `http://localhost:54321/odata/Traits?$expand=Lessons`

My final hurdle in migrating project from Net 461 to .Net Core 2 is [Creating Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4#creating-a-relationship-between-entities).

Specifically, when I try to call the following method, with the following request, I get a 404.

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "PUT")]        
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRef(
    [FromODataUri] int key, string navigationProperty, [FromBody] Uri link)
{
    ....  Do Work
}
```

Postman request:

```
http://localhost:54321/odata/Lessons(1)/Traits/$ref
```

body:

```
 {
    "@odata.id":"http://localhost:54321/OData/traits(1)"
 }
```

The following is my `Startup.Configure` method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    var builder = ConfigureOdataBuilder(app);

    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
        routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();
        routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

        // Work-around for #1175
        routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        routeBuilder.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); // enable mvc controllers
    });            
}

private ODataConventionModelBuilder ConfigureOdataBuilder(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices);

    builder.EntitySet<Lessons>(nameof(Lessons));
    builder.EntitySet<Traits>(nameof(Traits));       

    return builder;
}
```

**Question:** How do I reach this controller method?

Things I have tried,

- Rename CreateRef to CreateLink and Create
- Followed every link in these Git Issues, [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/939) and 
  [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/975#issuecomment-353488806).
- Read up on [Attribute Routing](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-03-attrribute-routing) spec.
- Tried solution based off this DeleteRef in this [Web Api oData v4 $ref 404 or server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678752/web-api-odata-v4-ref-404-or-server-error)
- Tried explicitly defining route with `[ODataRoute("Lessons({key})/{navigationProperty}")]`

Comment: Do you found a solution for this? I´m facing the same issue and wonder if something happend until now..?

Comment: We abandoned OData for .Net Core but here is a response to issue on github. [.NET Core Support - IN PROGRESS #939](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/939#issuecomment-381472886)

Comment: no good news.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a long way, but I finally found the answer.

```
[ODataRoute("lessons({lessonId})/traits({traitId})/$ref")]
public IActionResult CreateRef([FromODataUri] int lessonId, [FromODataUri] int traitId)
{
    //do work
}
```

Important: You have to call the id-params as I did. Don´t just call them Id - otherwise you´ll get a 404.

One more thing...

For those who tried the way from the microsoft docs - the Api-Names changed.. You don´t need them for this task, but if you have to convert an Uri to an OData-Path, here is an Uri-Extension doing this for you:

```
public static Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPath CreateODataPath(this Uri uri, HttpRequest request)
{
    var pathHandler = request.GetPathHandler();
    var serviceRoot = request.GetUrlHelper().CreateODataLink(
                            request.ODataFeature().RouteName, 
                            pathHandler, 
                            new List<ODataPathSegment>());

    return pathHandler.Parse(serviceRoot, uri.LocalPath, request.GetRequestContainer());
}
```

If you have an Uri like this: `http://localhost:54321/OData/traits(1)` you can split this into OData-segments to get e.g. the navigation: `returnedPath.NavigationSource` or the specified key: `returnedPath.Segments.OfType<KeySegment>().FirstOrDefault().Keys.FirstOrDefault().Value`